# Gerar Página de Download

Tags: php

Como faço para gerar uma página de download para os usuários clicarem em um link ou botão de download.

Esse é o meu script de upload remoto:

```
<form method="post">
<input name="url" size="50" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>

<?php

set_time_limit (24 * 60 * 60);

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) die();

$destination_folder = 'files/';

$url = $_POST['url'];
$newfname = $destination_folder . basename($url);

$file = fopen ($url, "rb");
if ($file) {
  $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

  if ($newf)
  while(!feof($file)) {
    fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
  }
}

if ($file) {
  fclose($file);
}

if ($newf) {
  fclose($newf);
}

?>
</center>
```

Comment: não entendi muito bem, você perguntou sobre como fazer um download mas postou um código de upload?! a localização desse arquivo está ou será armazenada na base de dados? Quer gerar um link de download após o upload? Sugiro uma melhor elaboração da questão.

Comment: esse é o script de upload remoto e quero que os envios que fizerem nele após o termino do upload aparecer um link para a página de download, Tipo o 4Shared ou Mega.

Comment: É fora de foco o que vou comentar mas dizer que isso aí é upload remoto, acho errado. O que esse script faz é ler uma página numa URL determinada pelo usuário e escrever o conteúdo num arquivo local. Não há nenhum processo de upload nisso, aliás, isso acima dá para fazer com "2 linhas de código" usando file_get_contents() and file_put_contents().

Answer (score 2):

Ok, após o upload então você redireciona para outro endereço e passe por parâmetro o nome gerado para o arquivo e nesse script você faz da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
  $file = "files/" . $_GET["arquivo"];

  if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
  }
?>
```

Maiores informações em: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php